# Why does button look weird?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

I am trying to make a button like this:

[image]

That is how it shows up in my XML layout editor, and I want it to show like that in my emulator also. However, it looks like this in my actual emulator and test devices:

[image]

Why is it not rounded? How can I make it more rounded? Here is my button:

```
    android:onClick = "messageButton"

    android:text="Make Custom Message"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"

    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:background="@drawable/messagebutton"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/helpbutton2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And here is the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="#A871A6"
        android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
        android:endColor="#33FF8B"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="250dp"
        android:height="83dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
</shape>
```

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: `topLeftRadius="100dp"`  that's  a very big radius. try with a smaller one

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks so much, that fixed it. Feel free to leave an answer, and I'll accept it. But, why does decreasing the radius fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounded rectangle radius is considered like below image. What you need is to set radius to half of your button height which is 63/2=~32dp

[image]